# Windows Driver : Install legacy hardware with command line tool

Tags: driver, setupapi, devcon

Operation System: Windows Server 2016 R2

I have a RAMDisk driver can be installed with "Add Legacy Hardware Wizard" (hdwwiz.exe) successfully. From the output of `devcon hwids *`, the device can be seen as below.

```
ROOT\UNKNOWN\0000
    Name: RAMDrive [ QSoft ] Enterprise (x64)
    Hardware IDs:
        ramdriv
```

However, I need complete the installation via Ansible, hence `hdwwiz.exe` cannot be used. It has to be done via command line without interaction.

I tried several approaches and none of them works.

---

#### Approach I : DevCon.exe (Windows Device Console)

```
C:\Ramdisk64_inst>devcon.exe install RAMDriv.inf ramdriv

Device node created. Install is complete when drivers are installed...
Updating drivers for ramdriv from C:\Ramdisk64_inst\RAMDriv.inf.
devcon.exe failed.

C:\Ramdisk64_inst>devcon.exe install RAMDriv.inf ROOT\UNKNOWN\0000

Device node created. Install is complete when drivers are installed...
Updating drivers for ROOT\UNKNOWN\0000 from C:\Ramdisk64_inst\RAMDriv.inf.
devcon.exe failed.
```

Here is the log from `C:\Windows\INF\setupapi.dev.log`

```
>>>  [Device Install (UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices) - ramdriv]
>>>  Section start 2018/12/20 07:10:35.670
      cmd: C:\Ramdisk64_inst\devcon.exe  install C:\Ramdisk64_inst\RAMDriv.inf ramdriv
     ndv: INF path: C:\Ramdisk64_inst\RAMDriv.inf
     ndv: Install flags: 0x00000001
!    ndv: Unable to find any matching devices.
<<<  Section end 2018/12/20 07:10:35.717
<<<  [Exit status: FAILURE(0xe000020b)]


>>>  [Device Install (UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices) - ROOT\UNKNOWN\0000]
>>>  Section start 2018/12/20 07:11:50.687
      cmd: devcon.exe  install RAMDriv.inf ROOT\UNKNOWN\0000
     ndv: INF path: C:\Ramdisk64_inst\RAMDriv.inf
     ndv: Install flags: 0x00000001
!    ndv: Unable to find any matching devices.
<<<  Section end 2018/12/20 07:11:50.734
<<<  [Exit status: FAILURE(0xe000020b)]
```

---

#### Approach 2 : DPInst.exe (Driver Package Installer)

```
C:\Ramdisk64_inst>dpinst.exe /PATH C:\Ramdisk64_inst /Q /C /LM

INFO:   Option set: dumping log info to console.
INFO:   Current working directory: 'C:\Ramdisk64_inst'
INFO:   Running on path 'C:\Ramdisk64_inst'
INFO:   No valid 'dpinst.xml' file provided.
INFO:   Install option set: Running in quiet mode. Suppressing Wizard and OS popups.
INFO:   Install option set: legacy mode on.
INFO:   Found driver package: 'C:\Ramdisk64_inst\RAMDriv.inf'.
INFO:   Preinstalling 'c:\ramdisk64_inst\ramdriv.inf' ...
INFO:   ENTER:  DriverPackagePreinstallW
INFO:   Driver package is already preinstalled 'c:\ramdisk64_inst\ramdriv.inf'.
SUCCESS:c:\ramdisk64_inst\ramdriv.inf is preinstalled.
INFO:   RETURN: DriverPackagePreinstallW  (0xB7)
INFO:   ENTER:  DriverPackageGetPathW
INFO:   RETURN: DriverPackageGetPathW  (0x0)
INFO:   ENTER:  DriverPackageInstallW
WARNING:DRIVER_PACKAGE_LEGACY_MODE flag set but not supported on Plug and Play driver on VISTA. Flag will be ignored.
INFO:   Installing INF file 'c:\ramdisk64_inst\ramdriv.inf' (Plug and Play).
INFO:   Looking for Model Section [DiskDevice.NTamd64]...
INFO:   No matching devices found in INF "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\ramdriv.inf_amd64_fcc99ac0622d865b\ramdriv.inf" on the Machine.
INFO:   No drivers installed. No devices found that match driver(s) contained in 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\ramdriv.inf_amd64_fcc99ac0622d865b\ramdriv.inf'.
INFO:   RETURN: DriverPackageInstallW  (0xE000020B)
INFO:   No matching device was found for 'c:\ramdisk64_inst\ramdriv.inf'. Driver will be installed when plugged in.
INFO:   Returning with code 0x100
```

---

#### Approach 3 : rundll32 calls SetupAPI

```
C:\Ramdisk64_inst>rundll32.exe setupapi.dll,InstallHinfSection DiskInstall 128 C:\Ramdisk64_inst\RAMDriv.inf
```

It ends without any error, but the driver is not installed.

---

#### Approach 4 : PnPUtil

```
C:\Ramdisk64_inst>pnputil.exe /add-driver C:\Ramdisk64_inst\RAMDriv.inf /install /subdirs /restart

Microsoft PnP Utility

Adding driver package:  RAMDriv.inf
Driver package added successfully.
Published Name:         oem7.inf
Driver package installed on matching devices.

Total driver packages:  1
Added driver packages:  1
```

It succeeded, but in fact driver is not installed.

---

None of them works. DpInst.exe says `No matching devices found in INF`, DevCon.exe says `Unable to find any matching devices`. It seems the same reason.

However the driver can be installed with `hdwwiz.exe` manually, does anyone know what is the secret inside `hdwwiz.exe`?

Comment: Did you solve the problem of installing "RamDriv". Could you post how you've done it? I've to install the same SW but with the description form the answer I don't get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Legacy Drivers can´t be installed with pnputil and have to use LaunchINFSectionEx-Call**

I tested the following and it works with several drivers from Windows 2000 up to Windows 10, 2012R2, 2016, 2019.

```
rundll32.exe advpack.dll,LaunchINFSectionEx ykmd.inf,Yubico64_Install.NT,,4,N
```

*Pay attention to use the correct section*

*The correct section of the inf-File must be used, when there is no [DefaultInstall]-Section*. This lacks in most answers. Look it up in your drivers inf-File and **use the correct section** (in my example "Yubico64_Install.NT"). Using the wrong section wont prompt an error. Im my example I use Quiet mode, no UI (4) and Never reboot (N) to install the driver automated via GPO. All options are documented in detail here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768006(v%3Dvs.85)